# 2 colour theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Take a square and draw a straight line right across it. Draw several more
lines in any arrangement so that the lines all cross the square, and the
square is divided into several regions. The task is to colour the regions in
such a way that adjacent regions are never coloured the same. (Regions
having only one point in common are not considered adjacent.) How few
different colours are needed to colour any such arrangement?

I tried specializing to 1,2,3 lines, but I do not know how to generalize to n lines. Any ideas?

I have a conjecture regarding these arrangements: one region is never adjacent to two regions that are adjacent to each other. How would one go about showing this?

Comment: Your conjecture follows easily after you show the regions can be properly coloured with $2$ colours.  In graph theoretical terms, you're showing that the (weak) dual graph of your arrangement is a bipartite graph, and a graph is bipartite if and only if it has no odd cycles (in particular, no cycles of length 3, which is your conjecture).

Comment: Would it be possible to reverse it and use my conjecture to prove colourability?

Comment: I doubt it, but perhaps these graphs have a special structure that I don't see right now. In general, you'd have to show that there are no cycles of length $5,7,9,\ldots$ in the weak dual (e.g., in terms of your arrangement this means a set of 5 regions $(A,B,C,D,E)$ with $A$ bordering $B$, $B$ bordering $C$, ..., and $E$ bordering $A$, and then similarly for every other odd number.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Do it by induction. When you add a new line, flip the colors of all regions on one side of the new line, from white to black and from black to white.